# Python sumar 1 en un archivo de texto

Tags: python, excel

Queria hacer una especie de database en excel que como se sabe se escribe por columnas y filas"Anumero", "Bnumero", "Cnumero"(A1,B1,C1)

Lo que estoy haciendo es que el usuario escriba un nombre y un numero de telefono y luego los escriba automaticamente en una fila y columna especifica(empezando por A1,B1), y que cuando lo vuelva a hacer sea el siguiente numero(A3,B3),(A4,B4) etc, por eso lo unico que encontre fue hacer un archivo .txt con solo el numero 0 y que cada vez que se ejecute mi codigo entre al archivo, al numero que esta escrito en el se le sume 1 y se cierre(sheet["A"+file]) = nombre[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre de la persona: ")
celular = input("Ingresa el celular de la persona: ")

sheet["A"+file] = nombre
sheet["B"+file] = celular

book.save("database.xlsx")
```

Comment: ¿Que versión de python estas usando python2 o python3?

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez me llamen loco por estar recomendando a todos que usen pandas :(, pero la verdad es que pandas es muy versátil para estas cosas. Con pandas no tenemos que preocuparnos por las columnas o índices, solo creamos un diccionario cuyas claves serán las columnas y el valor serán las filas.

**instalación**

```py
pip install pandas
```

**código**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre de la persona: ")
celular = input("Ingresa el celular de la persona: ")

#creamos el diccionario
data = [{
    "nombre":nombre,
    "celular":celular
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
path = "database.xlsx" #nombre del archivp
#el modo será a si el archivo existe, de lo contrario es w
mode = "a" if os.path.isfile(path) else "w" 

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode=mode) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, header=not (os.path.isfile(path) and os.stat(path).st_size != 0))
```

Pandas trabaja con *DataFrames*, esta es una estructura que nos permite manejar de distintas formas los datos, por ahora no hay mucho que explicar, pues esto solo no sirve para luego poder *exportar* el archivo como un `.xlsx`. Como quieres agregar datos al archivo necesitamos que estos se vayan añadiendo y no sobrescribiendo, podría hacer simplemente `df.to_excel(path)` pero esto sobrescribirá los datos, para evitar eso se tiene que especificar un *modo*, essto indica como será abierto el archivo.

- `a`: append, significa que agregará
- `w`: write, significa que escribirá.

En esta línea `mode = "a" if os.path.isfile(path) else "w"` decimos que la variable `mode` tendrá el valor de `a` para el caso que exista el archivo, si no existe, será `w`, esto por que si ponemos `a` y el archivo no existe esto dará un error.

Por mala suerte el método `to_excel` no soporta el atributo `mode` en su parámetro, a diferencia de `to_csv`. Por esa razón necesitamos otra clase de pandas que es `ExcelWriter`, esto nos provee de las herramientas necesarias para poder trabajar con un Excel y aquí si podemos especificar el parámetro `mode`

En el `header` será un valor `True` o `False`, esto depende de si existe o no el archivo, el `header` son las cabeceras (o nombres de las columnas) y no queremos que esto se agregue siempre, por eso se verifica la existencia del archivo, en caso exista no se le agrega el *header*, pero en caso no exista, si se agregará.

Por ultimo solo te recomiendo que uses archivos `.csv` pues hace las cosas más simples al momento de *exportarlo*, reduciendo todo a

```py
#...
df.to_csv(path,mode=mode , header= not (os.path.isfile(path) and os.stat(path).st_size != 0))
```

Comment: No creo que nadie te vea como un loco por recomendar Pandas, al contrario :D

Comment: pues sip, pero a todos los que vienen preguntando por openpyxl les termino diciendo que usen pandas :/, no esta mal pero bueno

Comment: danijela-popović me da un error en sheet[] = nombre(AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'), ademas la verdad no tengo ganas de aprender pandas ya que no creo que lo use nunca :/, como lo puedo solucionar

Comment: @AlanRichter Heee.... soy christian, esto se lo debes comentar a la otra respuesta. Por otra parte pandas es muy flexible y muy simple de usar para cosas como estas donde no tienes que preocuparte por las celdas y todo eso, al final tu tienes la decisión, yo solo te doy otra forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no simplificar las cosas? :)

Si no tienes ganas de aprender pandas desde cero (aunque tal vez no sea mala idea ), puedes abrir el archivo, leer el contenido, convertirlo en int con la función adecuada y agregarle 1, para después reconvertirlo en texto y escribir ese texto en el archivo.

```py
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

nombre_del_archivo = "archivo.txt" # el archivo con el número de la fila
nombre_del_documento = "base.xlsx"

if os.path.isfile(nombre_del_archivo): # comprueba si el archivo con el número existe
    # abre el archivo en modo de lectura+escritura 
    with open(nombre_del_archivo, "r") as f:
        # lee el contenido del archivo, lo convierte en tipo int y lo guarda en la variable fila
        fila = int(f.read())
else: # si el archivo no existe
    fila = 1

# solicita los datos
nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre de la persona: ")
celular = input("Ingresa el celular de la persona: ")

# comprueba si el documento ya existe
if os.path.isfile(nombre_del_documento):
    # abre el documento existente
    book = load_workbook(nombre_del_documento)
else:
    # el documento no existe, se crea un nuevo Workbook
    book = Workbook()
    fila = 1 # asegura que el nuevo documento empiece con la fila 1

# agrega el nombre y el celular a las celdas A y B, respectivamente, de la hoja activa
sheet = book.active
sheet.cell(row=fila, column=1, value=nombre)
sheet.cell(row=fila, column=2, value=celular)
book.save(nombre_del_documento) # guarda el documento Excel

with open(nombre_del_archivo, "w") as f:
    # le agrega 1 a la variable fila
    nuevo_numero_de_fila = fila + 1
    # reconvierte el nuevo número a texto (str) y lo guarda en el archivo
    f.write(str(nuevo_numero_de_fila))
```

#### Ediciones

- Simplificado el proceso de leer y escribir en el archivo con el número de la fila (el modo w+ lo complica un pelín)
- Agregada la comprobación de la existencia de dicho archivo, definiendo la `fila = 1` si el archivo no existe
- Agregada la funcionalidad de abrir el documento existente en vez de escribir sobre él (lo que borraría los datos ya guardados), y crear uno nuevo si no existe ya
- Cambiado el modo de especificar la celda y agregar los datos: uso del método `sheet.cell()`

Espero que ahora mi idea sí sea más clara y mi respuesta más conveniente, contribuyendo a una solución exitosa. :)

Comment: Saludos, intenta siempre agregar una explicación al código que propones (como es que soluciona el problema de OP, como funciona y si es posible link de documentación), recuerda que hay usuarios que son nuevos en programación y no entenderán tu respuesta, de esta manera tus respuestas ganarán más puntos. ;)

Comment: te puedes simplificar las cosas si abres el archivo en modo lectura y escritura `w+`

Comment: aparentemente el OP tiene problemas con tu respuesta (mira los comentarios de la mia :/ )