# Python openpyxl se superponen los valores

Tags: python, excel

Estoy haciendo una especie de database en excel con openpyxl(no se usar pandas y no tengo ganas de aprenderlo), lo que estoy haciendo es que en un archivo de texto esta el numero 1, el usuario ingresa un nombre y un numero de telefono y lo guarda en excel, cada vez que se ejecuta el codigo se suma 1 para que sea A1,A2,A3 y asi pero en las filas y columnas donde ya habia informacion me lo borra(si guardo el archivo antes de cerrarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre de la persona: ")
celular = input("Ingresa el celular de la persona: ")

with open("archivo.txt", "r") as file: #abre el archivo en formato leer
    numero = file.read() #lee el archivo y lo que esta ahi se guarda en numero
    nuevo_numero = int(numero) + 1 #el numero que este le suma 1 (2,3,4,5)
    file = open("archivo.txt", "w") #ahora lo abre en formato escribir
    file.write(str(nuevo_numero)) #escribe el numero nuevo(el anterior al que se le sumo 1)
    file.close()
    
    n1 = str(nuevo_numero) #agarra el nuevo numero y lo escribe en la fila y columna
    sheet["A"+n1] = nombre
    sheet["B"+n1] = celular
    book.save("database.xlsx") # guarda el documento Excel
```

Comment: En mi respuesta anterior explique el problema. Estas volviendo a guardar el archivo y no estas agregando los datos :/

Comment: El flag "w" sobre escribe todo el archivo, si no persistes los datos tras la lectura, estarás siempre escribiendo una fila de tu hoja.

Comment: voto por cerrar la pregunta...

Comment: me refiero a la hoja de excel, si quiero que el numero en archivo.txt se superponga con el modo "w", en la hoja de excel es lo que esta mal

Comment: en paco se guarda, y cuando lo vuelvo a hacer paco se elimina y pasa a paco2 que esta en la siguiente(eso si esta bien)

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso no puedes cerrarla, pero dime las razones y veré si voto por el cierre

Comment: @AlanRichter ya te dijeron que es lo que haces mal, solo busca como hacerlo en openpyxl

Comment: en stack overflow nunca ayudan :C

Comment: no siempre recibirás ayuda, algunas veces habrá personas que te guíen, déjame investigar algo y te aviso

Comment: ya encontre el error, tenias razon christian no estaba guardandolo estaba sobreescribiendolo, con book = openpyxl.load_workbook("database.xlsx") ahi si funciona

Comment: Yo te he ayudado en una pregunta. Además miré tus preguntas y veo que la gente ha intentado ayudarte (aunque no siempre con éxito). A veces simplemente puede no haber gente que sepa responder tus preguntas. Y también en esta pregunta te dijeron por que ocurría el error. Por que dices que aquí nunca ayudamos???

Answer (score 0):

> Si no tienes ganas de aprender pandas desde cero (aunque tal vez no sea mala idea ), puedes abrir el archivo, leer el contenido, convertirlo en int con la función adecuada y agregarle 1, para después reconvertirlo en texto y escribir ese texto en el archivo.
>
> - Simplificado el proceso de leer y escribir en el archivo con el número de la fila (el modo w+ lo complica un pelín)
> - Agregada la comprobación de la existencia de dicho archivo, definiendo la `fila = 1` si el archivo no existe
> - Agregada la funcionalidad de abrir el documento existente en vez de escribir sobre él (lo que borraría los datos ya guardados), y crear uno nuevo si no existe ya
> - Cambiado el modo de especificar la celda y agregar los datos: uso del método `sheet.cell()`

[Mi respuesta en la otra pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/473995/python-sumar-1-en-un-archivo-de-texto/474032#474032)

---

Para ser concretos, debes comprobar si existen los archivos antes de abrirlos para escribir, para no perder los datos existentes.

> Modo de sólo escritura (w). En este caso el archivo es truncado (vaciado) si existe, y se lo crea si no existe.
> [11.3. Modo de apertura de los archivos (Algoritmos de Programación con Python)](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/algoritmos-python/capitulo-11/modo-de-apertura-de-los-archivos)

---

También se debe cerrar un archivo antes de poderlo abrir para otra operación. En el código de esta pregunta, se intenta abrir el archivo para escribir antes de haber salido del `with` que lo abrió en modo de lectura.

[9.1. Sobre el objeto File (Python para principiantes)](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-9/sobre-el-objeto-file)

---

```py
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

nombre_del_archivo = "archivo.txt" # el archivo con el número de la fila
nombre_del_documento = "base.xlsx"

if os.path.isfile(nombre_del_archivo): # comprueba si el archivo con el número existe
    # abre el archivo en modo de lectura+escritura 
    with open(nombre_del_archivo, "r") as f:
        # lee el contenido del archivo, lo convierte en tipo int y lo guarda en la variable fila
        fila = int(f.read())
else: # si el archivo no existe
    fila = 1

# solicita los datos
nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre de la persona: ")
celular = input("Ingresa el celular de la persona: ")

# comprueba si el documento ya existe
if os.path.isfile(nombre_del_documento):
    # abre el documento existente
    book = load_workbook(nombre_del_documento)
else:
    # el documento no existe, se crea un nuevo Workbook
    book = Workbook()
    fila = 1 # asegura que el nuevo documento empiece con la fila 1

# agrega el nombre y el celular a las celdas A y B, respectivamente, de la hoja activa
sheet = book.active
sheet.cell(row=fila, column=1, value=nombre)
sheet.cell(row=fila, column=2, value=celular)
book.save(nombre_del_documento) # guarda el documento Excel

with open(nombre_del_archivo, "w") as f:
    # le agrega 1 a la variable fila
    nuevo_numero_de_fila = fila + 1
    # reconvierte el nuevo número a texto (str) y lo guarda en el archivo
    f.write(str(nuevo_numero_de_fila))
```

---

Hay muchas fuentes de documentación, habría que darles un buen uso.

Comment: Si explicaras tu respuesta sería excelente